# Trying to use a macro to create charts in google sheets but I can't figure out how to make it edit the y axis

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I've recently been trying to make a macro that will automatically adjust the bounds, and other things by creating new charts and deleting the old ones.  However, I'm unable to make the new charts have a y-axis title, or make any adjustments to the y-axis using the script.  I tried recording a macro that was just me copy and pasting a chart that had a y-axis title, but when I ran that macro the y-axis title didn't show up on the new chart either.  I've also tried a previous fix that I had seen, which was changing
`.setYAxisTitle('Kinematic Viscosity (cSt)')` to `setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Y output"}})` but that resulted in the error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"  I looked into possible reasons why that might be occurring, but I didn't see anything stand out that might be causing an issue like that.  I've attached part of my code here for reference:

```
   function CreateChart() {
   var ssf = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // Creates variable ssf which is the Google Sheets file
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ssf.getSheets()[1]);
  // Sets the Tabulated Properties Sheet (Sheet 2, if sheets are moved around, this needs to be changed) as the active sheet in the Google Sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Creates variable ss
  var Charts1 = ss.getCharts();
  for (var i in Charts1) {
    ss.removeChart(Charts1[i]);
  }
  // Removes all charts in Tabulated Properties
  var lrhr = ss.getRange("C17:D17");
  var clr = lrhr.getCell(1,1);
  var chr = lrhr.getCell(1,2);
  var lr = clr.getValue()/5;
  var hr = chr.getValue()/5;
  var difflr = (lr+17);
  var difflrr = 21+difflr;
  var diffrincell = 2+(hr - lr);
  // Creates a var diffrincell that is the length of the array that would be from the lower range to higher range
  var range0 = ss.getRange('U19:AL326');
  var range1 = ss.getRange('AM19:BD326')
  range0.copyValuesToRange(ss,39,51,19,326);
  //Creates dummy tables to be worked on to create graphs, preserving old tables that hold the formulas that call data
  var chead1 = ss.getRange(22,39,1,18);
  var head1 = ss.getRange(difflrr+1,39,1,18);
  chead1.copyTo(head1);
  // Changes headers for tables 1 and 2 (Dummy tables)
  var chead2 = ss.getRange(125,39,1,18);
  var head2 = ss.getRange(difflrr+104,39,1,18);
  chead2.copyTo(head2);
  // Changes headers for tables 3 and 4 (Dummy tables)
  var chead3 = ss.getRange(228,39,1,18);
  var head3 = ss.getRange(difflrr+207,39,1,18);
  chead3.copyTo(head3);
  
  var range2 = ss.getRange(1,1,diffrincell);
  var range3 = range2.offset(difflrr,38);
  // Creates X axis range
  var range4 = ss.getRange(difflrr+1,39,diffrincell,18);
  var range5 = ss.getRange(difflrr+104,39,diffrincell,18);
  var range6 = ss.getRange(difflrr+207,39,diffrincell,18);
  //creates ranges for all the data in the dummy tables, seperated for easier access for creating charts.
  var col1 = 40;
  var col2 = 41;
  var col3 = 42;
  var col4 = 43;
  var col5 = 44;
  var col6 = 45;
  var col7 = 46;  
  var col8 = 47;
  
  var col9 = 49;
  var col10 = 50;
  var col11 = 51;
  var col12 = 52;
  var col13 = 53;
  var col14 = 54;
  var col15 = 55;
  var col16 = 56;
  
  var row1 = difflrr+1;
  var row2 = difflrr+104;
  var row3 = difflrr+207;
  var rown = diffrincell;
  
  Charts1[0] = ss.newChart()
  .asLineChart()
  .addRange(range3)
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row1,col1,rown,1))
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row1,col9,rown,1))
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row2,col1,rown,1))
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row2,col9,rown,1))
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row3,col1,rown,1))
  .addRange(ss.getRange(row3,col9,rown,1))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.SHOW_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('curveType', 'function')
  .setOption('legend.position', 'top')
  .setOption('domainAxis.direction', 1)
  .setOption('title', 'Kinematic Viscosity')
  .setOption('treatLabelsAsText', false)
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.alignment', 'center')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('hAxis.formatOptions.prefix', '')
  .setOption('hAxis.formatOptions.source', 'data')
  .setOption('hAxis.direction', 1)
  .setOption('hAxis.formatOptions.scaleFactor', 1)
  .setXAxisTitle('Temperature (°C)')
  .setRange(-40, 135)
  .setOption('hAxis.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "y axis"}})
  .setOption('vAxes.minorGridlines.count', 0)
  .setYAxisTitle('Kinematic Viscosity (cSt)')
  .setOption('vAxes.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('height', 427)
  .setOption('width', 691)
  .setPosition(1, 10, 81, 0)
  .build();
  ss.insertChart(Charts1[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

for the y-axis, there are two option keys...

> `vAxes` - is used for charts with multiple y-axis'
> if you use this option, you need to specify the y-axis index, where `0` is the first index

> `vAxis` - is used to set options for all y-axis' on the chart

based on this, you should probably change the following to `vAxis`
the error might have been a result of not specifying an axis index

```
.setOption('vAxes.minorGridlines.count', 0)
.setOption('vAxes.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
```

change to...

```
.setOption('vAxis.minorGridlines.count', 0)
.setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
```

for the title itself, try...

```
.setOption("vAxis.title", "y axis")
```

Comment: `setOption('hAxis.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('vAxis.minorGridlines.count', 0)
  .setOption('vAxis.title','Kinematic Viscosity (cSt)')
  .setOption('vAxis.titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('height', 427)
  .setOption('width', 691)
  .setPosition(1, 10, 81, 0)
  .build();`   This unfortunately did not work either